# JavaScript Uncaught Reference when using setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am using d3.js to make data visualization but I am not a JavaScript programmer so I wrote something like the following

```
        for(var i =0;i<6;i++){
          setTimeout(function(){
            var in = data[0][i];
            slate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
            var svg = d3.select("#clustering").append("svg")
                    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
            svg.append("rect")
                    .attr("width", width)
                    .attr("height", height);

            svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "x axis")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                    .call(xAxis);

            svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "y axis")
                    .call(yAxis);

            var color = d3.scale.category10();
            refreshGraph();
                },1000);
            }
        /*
        * function displaying data on svg
        * called every time data change
        */
        var refreshGraph = function(){

            // removing all previously drawn dots
            svg.selectAll(".dot")
            .data(instruments)
            .exit()
            .remove();
          }
```

But I got this error `Uncaught Reference Error: svg is not defined`  I know the function `refreshGraph` can not see the `var svg`, but I don't know how to fix this.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: When you use setTimeout in a loop I believe you need to make it into anonymous function using variable. I had similar issue but not with d3

Comment: "I know the function refreshGraph can not see the var svg" — Nor can anything else. It doesn't appear anywhere in the code you shared.

Comment: Well, in this piece of code, I don't see svg defined anywhere...

Comment: @Riddell: That's not the problem the OP is asking about. But it *is* the *next* problem they'd have. Omar: For more on that, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: @Riddell as I said I am not a JavaScript programmer can you please explain in code. thank you

Comment: @Quentin I edited the code snippet

Comment: try Console.Log(svg) and see if it's defined on each loop cycle. Use Chrome Devtools and set up some breakpoints

Comment: @beerwin I edited the code snippet

Comment: @Riddell it's defined inside the loop but it's not inside the function refreshGraph()

Comment: [var svg] define the svg variable above your loop. then in your loop change it to svg = d3.select("#clustering").append("svg")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either:

- Define the function you assign to `refreshGraph` inside the function you pass to `setTimeout` so that `svg` is still in scope *or*
- Declare `svg` *outside* the loop entirely so it remains in scope *or*
- Pass `svg` to that function as an argument when you call it